# How was wearing her purse an evidence that lead to the capture of Anna?

Tags: plot-explanation, anna

In the 2019 movie *Anna* we see the CIA officer capture **Anna** right after she attempts to assassinate the German guy.

> Anna: How did you catch me?
>
> CIA Guy: The way you put on your purse

Then we see a flashback of her putting on her purse in two shots from the movie. One of them is right after she was questioned for the first time, and the other was when she was at the hotel.

The question is: How is that an evidence against her?

I mean: she never denied or pretended to be someone else, to the point that wearing the purse gave her out! She was consistent all along.

Unless I am missing something.

Comment: Do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anna_(2019_film) ?

Comment: Also: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7456310/faq

Comment: @BCdotWEB the answer from imdb satisfies as an answer. Can you post it so that I may accept it? or should I delete the question?

Comment: @Ahmad In any case, don't delete the question. Rather than that people should maybe instead post proper answers than just comment links to other places.

Comment: I haven't seen the movie so I don't know whether the IMDb answer is correct.

Comment: in question title you ask "capture of Anne?". do you mean Anna?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When walking out, she was carrying her purse in the other hand.

I think this is a ridiculously thin argument, boarding on simply having a poor story line and not bothering to improve it - most women might have a habit to carry their purses always in the same hand, but that's hardly a reason to conclude they are a double just because they hold it in the other hand once (would you assume your wife / friend is a double because she uses her other hand for her purse once?)

Consider though that the CIA probably doesn't need 'legal prove' to take you in; and maybe all that is meant is that 'the other hand' gave them *the idea of a double*, and then they dug deeper into it and found prove.

Answer (score 0):

The woman leaving the hotel (decoy lady posing as Anna M) carried her bag on her right hand dropped down on the side.
The CIA agent observed through hours of surveillance that the real Anna M always carried her bag on the hook of her left arm. He deduced (although, agree, by a long shot) that the decoy was not Anna M based on how she carried her bag.

Comment: Yes, that was a dead giveaway as people don't change habits.